# ResharperUltimate - disable ReSpeller

Tags: resharper

How can I disable this plugin from resharper options in Visual Studio? Driving me crazy, I've unchecked all checkboxes from `resharper->options->ReSpeller` yet it persists to underline every single string (writing in czech) with green.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Untick `ReSpeller` checkbox under `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Products & Features` and restart Visual Studio.

Also, you can install additional dictionaries to support non-English languages. ReSpeller supports Hunspell/MySpell dictionaries, which can be added under `ReSharper | Options | Environment | ReSpeller` page.

Comment: You can also set the inspection level to hint instead of disabling the feature entirely. Click the ReSpeller icon on the left, inspection in the bottom and set severity level to hint. It will just be three green dots under the word then. It is much less intrusive but you still get the notification in case you actually did make a typo in an english string and you would want to correct it.